# How do I get an object inside a document in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query a specific object from a document's field

I have stored it as an object but I'm unable to get it as an object

[image: My firestore setup]

```
   var ref = db.collection("users/${myauth.currentUser?.uid}/courses").document(docs[position].id)
       ref.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
           val mday = documentSnapshot.toObject(mday::class.java)
           Log.w("",mday.dayname)
       }
```

`mday` is the object I'm trying to get

`mon` for example is an `mday` object

Comment: You said you're unable to get it as an object. So what's the return type that you're getting?

Comment: its returning me a document snapshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get($dayname.time_array")
```

fixed it